# JSON Schema for Array items to allow one type only once in any order

Tags: jsonschema

I was wondering how to define a schema for an array that would allow for a type to only be allowed once, but also allow any other types n multiple times ( or allow any other type multiple times ) independent of order.

Valid:

```
[ allowMany, allowMany, allowOnce, allowMany, allowOther]
[ allowOnce allowMany, allowMany, allowMany, allowOther]
[ allowOther, allowOnce, allowMany, allowOther]
```

Invalid:

```
[allowOnce, allowMany, allowOther, allowOnce]
[allowOnce, allowOnce]
```

I looked at `contains` and tried to come up with the `items` schema.  The problem is that I don't care about order so the tuple option doesn't work.  And defining an `items` schema doesn't account for types appearing multiple times.

Any one have a suggestion?

Comment: You may be interested in the forthcoming draft 8 which adds `minContains` and `maxContains` keywords.  These keywords allow you to specify the min and max for the number of items that match the schema declared by the `contains` keyword.  https://json-schema.org/work-in-progress/WIP-jsonschema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4.4  Unfortunately, I don't think it can be done with draft 7 or earlier.

Comment: Thanks @gregsdennis .  I guess I'll have to keep an eye out for when that is released.

Comment: No worries. It should be soon if we can be happy with it and stop tweaking.